# Send Signature Pad to php POST method.

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use signature pad to post some data 
this is the form for the and back end
every time i post i got a empty image there is no problem 
i don't know is it the image decode ?
or it's input value ??

```
    <form action="" method="POST" id="form-submit" name="myform">
    <section>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="boxarea">
            <div class="signature-pad" id="signature-pad">
              <div class="m-signature-pad">
                <div class="m-signature-pad-body">
                  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="625" height="318"></canvas>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    <input type="hidden" id='image' name="image" value=""> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

`<script>
    var imageData = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    document.getElementsByName("image")[0].setAttribute("value", imageData);
  </script>`

```
$img = $_POST['image'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = './signature-image/' . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
$image=str_replace('./','',$file);
```

Comment: You should inspect your network request and see what data is posted..

Comment: Change `.setAttribute("value", imageData)` to `.setAttribute("src", imageData)`. `imageData` is just a url.

Comment: @clabe45 when i change it to .setAttribute("src", imageData) it didn't pass any data

Comment: @Tetsh how do you know it didn't pass any data? Have you tried getting the attribute?

Comment: @clabe45 when i use it i got an image with 0Kb ... in normal i got a blank image with 4.13Kb

Comment: Ah I see you need to use `value` because it's a form. Sorry!

Comment: @Panther i don't find anything ... no warning no error

Comment: can you tell me where your script tag is placed and when it is invoked ?

Comment: @Panther my script tag in the same view page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your script tag executes on page load. You need to execute it right before you submitting your form. Since you are executing it on page load, the canvas would be empty at that time. You have to get the image data from the canvas and set it to the value before submitting so that the draw data is transferred to the form value and in turn goes to server when you submit the form.

If you have jQuery, you may try something like below.

First write your signaturePad inside a function like this

```
function getSignaturePad() {
 var imageData = signaturePad.toDataURL();
 document.getElementsByName("image")[0].setAttribute("value", imageData);
}
```

Then, use jQuery to bind the form and call the function before submitting like below

```
$('#form-submit').submit(function() {
  getSignaturePad(); // call this function here, sets the imageData right before submitting the form.
  return true; // returning true submits the form. 
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much ... it's perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

You're not grabbing the canvas element; `toDataURL()` works on the canvas element, in your case that's `myCanvas`.

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var imageData = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementsByName("image")[0].setAttribute("value", imageData);
</script>
```

Source : [toDataURL() doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)